# "Context Resolution" Task in NLP

Tags: nlp

I'm looking for references to a standard(-ish) task/dataset in NLP that is close(-ish) to the following: we have a document with a list of references (sorry), for example, a scientific paper. For every reference, we have a sentence within the document and the corresponding text of another paper. The task is to find sentences/regions within the corresponding text, that "support" the sentence in the original text, given some metric. Basically, what anyone would do given cumbersome unexplained statement within some mind-boggling paper.

Apart from the main question, what are the possible/good/standard metrics one can use? Are there remarkable implementations/users of some in-house solutions/any other useful remarks?